# How build a function callback in typescript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm trying to do a callBack function in typescript and a tutorial explains that we have to do this with ref.
I succeed to use scrollIntoView in a reference (component home), but when I am trying in the same way to create ref for a callback function it doesn't work ...

I got this error:

```
TypeError: routerRef.current.scrollToSection is not a function
```

I tried without the current but it's the same issue:

```
TypeError: routerRef.scrollToSection is not a function
```

Could you help me please ?

My header component:

```js
const Header = () => {


    const routerRef :any = useRef(React.createRef());

    function scrollToSection(section : number){
        routerRef.scrollToSection(section);
    }



    return (
        ...
                        <li className="navbar_item_title" onClick={() => scrollToSection(1)}>{text[language].home} </li>
                        <li className="navbar_item_title" onClick={() => scrollToSection(2)}>{text[language].my_portrait} </li>
                        <li className="navbar_item_title" onClick={() => scrollToSection(3)}>{text[language].contact}</li>
...
            <Router ref={routerRef} updateNavBarDisplay={updateNavBarDisplay}></Router>
    );
}
export default Header;
```

My router component:

```js
interface Props {
    ref: any
}
const Router = () => {

    const homeRef :any = useRef(React.createRef());

    function scrollToSection(section : number){
        homeRef.scrollToSection(section);
    }

    return (
        <BrowserRouter>
            <Switch>
                <Route exact path="/" render={() => <Home ref={homeRef} updateNavBarDisplay={updateNavBarDisplay} />} />
                <Route path="*" component={NotFound} />
            </Switch>
        </BrowserRouter>
    );
}
export default Router;
```

My home component:

```js
const Home = () => {

    const sectionRef1: any = useRef(React.createRef());
    const sectionRef2: any = useRef(React.createRef());

    const scroll = (ref: any) => {
        ref.current.scrollIntoView({
            behavior: 'smooth',
            block: 'start',
        });
    };

    function scrollToSection(section: number) {
        if (section === 1) {
            scroll(sectionRef1);
        }
        else if (section === 2) {
            scroll(sectionRef2);
        }
        else if (section === 3) {
            //TODO: active button
        }
    }
    return (
        <div>
            <div ref={sectionRef1} />
            <VisibilitySensor partialVisibility={true} onChange={onChange}>
                <Carrousel></Carrousel>
            </VisibilitySensor>
            <div ref={sectionRef2} />
            <Portrait></Portrait>

        </div>
    );
}
export default Home;
```

I deleted some part of code to be clearer.

I hope you could tell me what is wrong, thanks in advance !

Comment: const scrollToSection = (section : number) => {
        routerRef.scrollToSection(section);
    } - does changing it to this do something ?

Comment: Also why do you need to have `React.createRef()` inside of `useRef` ?  the ref will be created even without it

Comment: Thank you for your help, but it doesn't change the issue :/